# Synonym for pointing out someone's wrong behaviour

Tags: word-request

What are verbs of phrases describing making a strict remark condemning someone's wrong behavior to one's face? For example, when a pupil keeps chatting during a class and the teacher asks him to stop.

Comment: You mean something like **"Stop it immediately"** or **"Stop it now"**?

Comment: @SovereignSun what the teacher actually says doesn't matter, I mean only the situation in general.

Comment: @SovereignSun No no no, I mean the act of making a remark by the teacher. Or receiving one by the pupil.

Comment: There are nouns like **"discourtesy"**, **"effrontery "**, **"impropriety"** and **"familiarity"**

Comment: @SovereignSun Right, so I mean the act of telling a pupil about his discourtesy and demanding to stop it.

Comment: Or maybe **"reprimand"** or **"call-down"**? Maybe even **"rebuke"** or **"scold"**?

Comment: Reprimand -- @SovereignSun is perfect. We also used to say, "He's been "**schooled**".

Comment: (These may only apply in BrE) The most common one at my school was **"tell off"**. There is also **"rollicking"** and it's slightly more rude, slang cousin **"bollocking"**.

Comment: There are many, many possible answers to this question.  Can you narrow down a bit more what you are looking for?  (Formal/informal?  Severe/gentle?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

reprimand (noun and verb); scold (verb), scolding (noun); rebuke (noun and verb); upbraid (verb)

Comment: They are all slightly different in color and definition but do fit in.